# The Vowel Eater II

Tags: knowledge, english, quote

Here's a quote from a very famous book with all the vowels and punctuation removed. Can you re-assemble it?

> wndrfvbnchngdnthnghtltmthnkwsthsmwhngtpthsmrnnglmstthnkcnrmmbrflnglttldffrnt

([Hat-tip.](/q/40829))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The restored text is

> "I wonder if I've been changed in the night? Let me think: was I the same when I got up this morning? I almost think I can remember feeling a little different."

which is a quote from

> *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*.

Comment: +1 Beat me by seconds. Had literally just copied it from goodreads.

Comment: Beat me by seconds too. Alas.

Comment: @msh20 has a fascination with the Book of Alice. :P

Comment: I would be very pleased to know how you worked it out.